Oh my zsh theme interferes inter key (Ctrl C)
I'm using iterm2 and I have zsh with oh my zsh theme working well in my laptop. I did the same setup on my server when I am using ssh. However, when I activate any theme, Ctrl C behaves strangely and it waits to press a key before going to a new line!
I checked stty and everything seems normal. I also tried different things like switching to terminal instead of Iterm or deactivating the plugins (I only have git).
It only happens when I add the line ZSH_THEME="theme_name". Is there anything else I can check?
P.S. I narrowed it down to git_prompt_info in the robbyrussel theme.

Are you really running iterm2 on Ubuntu - or is this a question about Mac?

I'm using Mac to ssh to an Ubuntu server, the problem is in Ubuntu. I mentioned iterm2 for potential key binding conflicts.
